# ArrayList of function pointer

Tags: c, arraylist

i'm creating a List backed by a `void*` array. This particular arraylist will copy the memory content of what is added to it, so the passed-in parameter has no effect on the content of the list. When the array gets full it is incremented by 75% of it current size. One usage of that array is to store function pointers.

There is something going on that i can insert and pull out values of the arraylist but the memory address of the functions are coming out wrong.

Here is a small program that ilustrate the issue. The expected result is to write 'fun1' and 'fun2' in the console, but the program aborts with a `0xC0000005 :: Access Violation`.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char       u8;
typedef unsigned short      u16;
typedef unsigned int        u32;
typedef unsigned long long  u64;

typedef struct {
    u32 capacity;
    u32 used;
    u64 stride;
    void* payload;
} ArrayList;

ArrayList* arraylist_create(u64 stride) {
    ArrayList* array = malloc(sizeof(ArrayList));
    if (array == NULL) printf("%s", "Failed to malloc(sizeof(ArrayList))");

    array->capacity = 1;
    array->stride = stride;
    array->used = 0;
    array->payload = malloc(stride);

    return array;
}

void arraylist_add(ArrayList* list, void* payload) {
    if (list == NULL) return;

    // Resize by 1.75 of current capacity
    if (list->used == list->capacity) {
        u32 new_capacity = (list->capacity * 1.75) + 1;

        void* block = malloc(list->stride * new_capacity);
        memcpy(block, list->payload, list->stride * list->capacity);
        free(list->payload);

        list->payload = block;
        list->capacity = new_capacity;
    }

    u64* address = (u64*) list->payload;
    memcpy((void*)(address + list->used), payload, list->stride);
    list->used++;
}

void fun1(void) { printf("%s", "fun1"); }
void fun2(void) { printf("%s", "fun2"); }
typedef void (*pfn)(void);

int main(void) {
    ArrayList* array = arraylist_create(sizeof(pfn));
    arraylist_add(array, fun1);
    arraylist_add(array, fun2);

    u64* address = array->payload;
    for (u8 i = 0; i < array->used; ++i) {
        void* function = address + i;
        ((pfn) function)();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nit, but your typedefs are wrong. If you want aliases for `u8...64`, you should be aliasing `uint(8|16|32|64)_t` from `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: btw you can use `realloc` instead of a manual `malloc`+`memcpy`, plus it can perform better in some cases (where the allocation could extended in-place).

Comment: yet another note... Your stride needs to be the size from `sizeof`, _rounded up_ to the nearest alignment from `alignof`. In many cases the its the same, but it won't be if you have any structs that need padding (e.g. a struct with a `u16` and a `u8` will need 1 byte of padding, so its stride is 4, even though its size is only 3) See `posix_memalign()` and `aligned_alloc()` for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know *exactly* what the issue is, but the `memcpy((void*)(address + list->used), payload, list->stride)` part is really sus. I got it working by just making the payload a double pointer (a pointer to a buffer of void pointers):

```
typedef struct {
    u32 capacity;
    u32 used;
    u64 stride;
-    void* payload;
+    void** payload;
} ArrayList;

// ...

void arraylist_add(ArrayList* list, void* payload) {
     // ...
-    memcpy((void*)(address + list->used), payload, list->stride);
+    list->payload[list->used] = payload;
     list->used++
}
```

I also added a `arraylist_get` function, and some more debugging info:

```c
void* arraylist_get(ArrayList* list, off_t index) {
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;
    
    return list->payload[index];
}

void fun1(void) { printf("Hello from fun1\n"); }
void fun2(void) { printf("Hello from fun2\n"); }
typedef void (*pfn)(void);

int main(void) {
    ArrayList* array = arraylist_create(sizeof(pfn));
    arraylist_add(array, (void *)fun1);
    arraylist_add(array, (void *)fun2);
    
    printf("fun1 address: %p\n", (void *)fun1);
    printf("fun2 address: %p\n\n", (void *)fun2);
    for (u8 i = 0; i < array->used; ++i) {
        printf("array[%i] = %p\n", i, arraylist_get(array, i));
        
        void* function = arraylist_get(array, i);
        ((pfn) function)();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And it *works on my machine™*:

```
fun1 address: 0x104cefdbc
fun2 address: 0x104cefdd8

array[0] = 0x104cefdbc
Hello from fun1
array[1] = 0x104cefdd8
Hello from fun2
```

Comment: The main point of that structure is to have one continous block of memory. When i assign a reference to something outside the list then iterations starts to do some memory jumps and cache misses. Thats why the memcpy where in there. I will play around with the `**`idea

Comment: @BrunoAraújo This is still one continuous block of memory (notice I didn't change the `array->payload = malloc(stride);` part). Looking again, I see what you're going for, with the `stride` variable allowing you to support elements smaller or larger than a `sizeof(void *)`. But in any case, you'll always have two layer of indirection here. You can't put functions into a buffer by-value in C. They're always referenced by pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Like Alexander said in his answer. Your pointer math looks really suspicious.

To get it to work, I changed this:

```
u64* address = (u64*) list->payload;
memcpy((void*)(address + list->used), payload, list->stride);
```

To this:

```
unsigned char* dst = list->payload;
dst += list->used * list->stride;
memcpy(dst, payload, list->stride);
```

The above has the added benefit of not assuming pointers are 8 bytes.

And since function pointers by themselves are weird enough as they get casted to/from other types, let's invent a container for them:

```
struct Container {
    pfn fn;
};
```

As such, your main needs similar adjustments for both the container and the pointer math.

```
int main(void) {
    ArrayList* array = arraylist_create(sizeof(struct Container));

    struct Container c1 = { fun1 };
    struct Container c2 = { fun2 };

    arraylist_add(array, &c1);
    arraylist_add(array, &c2);

    for (u8 i = 0; i < array->used; ++i) {
        unsigned char* src = array->payload;
        struct Container* container = src + array->stride * i;
        container->fn();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above works for me. And since we got rid of the u64 hacks, the above should work on 32-bit and 64-bit systems alike.